Mocked DbContext throws exception when execute async operations
I have the following problem, maybe one of you had something similar. I want to mock DbContext to test my repository class. This is a code which i want to test:
public async Task<bool> IsUserAlreadyAddReview(Guid userId, Guid bookId)
{
    return await _dbContext
        .Set<Domain.Entities.Review.Review>()
        .AnyAsync(x => x.BookId == new BookId(bookId) &&
                    x.ReviewCreatedBy == new UserId(userId) &&
                    x.ReviewDeletedOn == null);
}

In my project I'm using TypedId.
I implemented some class from this tutorial to be able to mock DbContext and with successful result. Then I noticed, that I also need mock async executor of DbContext method, so I tried to implement AsyncQueryProvider:
DbAsyncEnumerable
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace X.Test.BuildingBlocks.Moq;

internal class DbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public DbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) : base(enumerable) { }

    public DbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression) : base(expression) { }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => new DbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this);
}

DbAsyncEnumerator
namespace X.Test.BuildingBlocks.Moq;

internal class DbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public DbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public T Current => _inner.Current;

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
        return new ValueTask(Task.CompletedTask);
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
    {
        return new ValueTask<bool>(_inner.MoveNext());
    }
}

DbAsyncQueryProvider
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace X.Test.BuildingBlocks.Moq;

internal class DbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

    public DbAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object? Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        try
        {
            return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression); // Exception
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
    }

    TResult IAsyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }
}

Try catch block is only for reason to indicate, where error occurs.
I also create mock factory
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Moq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace X.Test.BuildingBlocks.Moq;

public class DbContextMock
{
    public static TContext GetMock<TData, TContext>(
        List<TData> mockData,
        Expression<Func<TContext, DbSet<TData>>> dbSetSelectionExpression
    ) where TData : class where TContext : DbContext
    {
        var mockDataQueryable = mockData.AsQueryable();
        var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<TData>>();
        var dbContextMock = new Mock<TContext>();

        dbSetMock
            .As<IAsyncEnumerable<TData>>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken.None))
            .Returns(new DbAsyncEnumerator<TData>(mockDataQueryable.GetEnumerator()));

        dbSetMock
            .As<IQueryable<TData>>()
            .Setup(x => x.Provider)
            .Returns(new DbAsyncQueryProvider<TData>(mockDataQueryable.Provider));

        dbSetMock
            .As<IQueryable<TData>>()
            .Setup(x => x.Expression)
            .Returns(mockDataQueryable.Expression);

        dbSetMock
            .As<IQueryable<TData>>()
            .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
            .Returns(mockDataQueryable.ElementType);

        dbSetMock
            .As<IQueryable<TData>>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(mockDataQueryable.GetEnumerator());

        dbSetMock
            .Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TData>()))
            .Callback<TData>(mockData.Add);

        dbSetMock
            .Setup(x => x.AddRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<TData>>()))
            .Callback<IEnumerable<TData>>(mockData.AddRange);

        dbSetMock
            .Setup(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<TData>()))
            .Callback<TData>(x => mockData.Remove(x));

        dbSetMock
            .Setup(x => x.RemoveRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<TData>>()))
            .Callback<IEnumerable<TData>>(x =>
            {
                foreach (var y in x)
                {
                    mockData.Remove(y);
                }
            });

        dbContextMock
            .Setup(dbSetSelectionExpression)
            .Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

        return dbContextMock.Object;
    }
}

Test which throws an error
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public async Task ReviewRepository_WhenIsUserAlreadyAddReview_ThenDataAreCorrect(
    Guid bookIdMock,
    Guid userIdMock
)
{
    // Arrange
    var reviewMock = new List<Revrent.Domain.Entities.Review.Review>
    {
        ReviewMock
            .CreateMock()
            .WithBookId(bookIdMock)
            .WithUserId(userIdMock)
            .Generate(),
        
        ReviewMock
            .CreateMock()
            .WithBookId(bookIdMock)
            .Generate()
    };

    var dbContextMock = DbContextMock.GetMock<Revrent.Domain.Entities.Review.Review, DbContext>(reviewMock, x => x.Set<Revrent.Domain.Entities.Review.Review>());

    var reviewRepository = new X.Persistance.Domains.Review.ReviewRepository(dbContextMock);

    // Act
    var result = await reviewRepository.IsUserAlreadyAddReview(userIdMock, bookIdMock);

    // Assert
    Assert.True(result);
}

The problem is when this test execute, I get an error says:

Argument expression is not valid

in DbAsyncQueryProvider.
However, when i change repository code from .AnyAsync() to .Any() and remove await, then everything seems working great.

Ask yourself the question what you're actually testing when running  IsUserAlreadyAddReview. If the test is green it only tells that a painstakingly devised memory model leads to the expected result. You still don't know it the method succeeds in reality. Also, passing flat Guid parameters defeats the purpose of typed Ids.

TypeId are used on deeper layer of Clean Architecture (Domain) when I have method like Delete(TypedId) but that's not the point. I give an example with most simplified method which I had. Maybe this is not the best case to unit test, but I had other method which contains more logic and require properly unit testing.
